# Bootstrap extra space on right

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am unsure why I have a lot of extra space on the right of the site when I use Bootstrap for a wordpress blog.

http://peterzapfella.com/

If you load the page, you will see you can scroll right and you will see white space. When I validate the site I get the GREEN light saying that it is valid, and I can't seem to figure out why the space is there, could someone please see if they have better luck debugging this.

I could understand if I have missed a DIV or something but according to http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpeterzapfella.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 I have not.

Comment: There is a div with class `pagination` which also has `container` class that gives it width `1070px`. Remove that `container` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are using "container" class with "pagination" class and "container" class has "width: 970px;" css style.

Please use below code to fix issue.

in HTML:

```
<div class="pagination"></div>
```

or in CSS insert below code:

```
.pagination.container{width:100%}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its possibly because of this

```
<div class="pagination container"></div>
```

Removing this removes extra space on right side.

Answer (score 0):

As is this HTML bit:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 cont-grid">
```

To be:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-12 cont-grid">
```

the col-md-9 is extra in the second div.